# How to change Install button display text conditionally

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

Is it possible to change the "Install" button display text based on some condition i.e if fresh install then "Install" if upgrade then "Update"?

Basically, on major upgrade i am skipping some of my custom dialogs (which are shown on fresh installation) so on InstallReady dialog i want to show "Update" instead of "Install" as the button text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that but you'll need a custom "VerifyReadyDlg" dialog. You can just show the "Upgrade" or "Install" button depending on the upgrade/install like it is done for other options which present there (Remove/Change/etc).

Just check out the VerifyReadyDlg (the built-in wix dialog).

Comment: this is exactly what i was thinking about. Instead of hide/show, i would simple show custom VerifyReadyDlg on Upgrade (with changed display captions) and Wix VerifyReadyDlg on install.